# From group ring to ring ring?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

For a group $G$, the set $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ of all formal $\mathbb{Z}$ linear combinations is a ring with unit. Now the set $\mathbb{Z}[\mathbb{Z}[G]]$ gets the structure of a ring from the addition in $\mathbb{Z}[G]$, but the group structure of $G$ also yields a composition on $\mathbb{Z}[\mathbb{Z}[G]]$.

More generally, let $R$ be a ring and consider the group algebra $\mathbb{Z}[R]$ induced from the additive group structure. It is convenient to write the basis elements in the form $e^r$ with $r\in R$, because then $e^{r+s}=e^re^s$.
Now one can introduce a new composition by the $\mathbb Z$-bilinear extension of $e^r\square e^s=e^{rs}$.
Then $\square$ defines another ring structure on $\mathbb{Z}[R]$  and it is distributive with respect to the first multiplication.

Have these structures been investigated? Is the functor $R\mapsto \mathbb{Z}[R]$ adjoint to the forgetful functor from the category of (whatever the structure is called) to the category of rings?

Comment: I think group rings are mainly interesting because modules $M$ over them correspond to $G$-representations, i.e. group hohomorphisms $G\to Aut(M)$. I cannot see an analog of a $G$-representation, when $G$ is a ring.

Comment: I don't know if this structure has a name but I essentially took advantage of it in Theorem 4.3 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/2108.02166.pdf. If K is a field and R is a finite frobenius ring then I showed the monoid algebra KR of the multiplicative monoid of R is Frobenius in good characteristic using that KR is also the underlying vector space of the group algebra of the additive group. The interaction between the two structures that you point out is used essentially in the argument but I didn't explicitly define some sort of new algebraic structure

Comment: The group ring $\mathbb{Z}[\mathbb{Z}[G]]$ has a coproduct and two products, along with its addition. Such gadgets arise also in algebraic topology: a "Hopf ring" has a coproduct and two products, along with their ordinary addition. Hopf rings arise naturally from the UNSTABLE operations on a generalized homology theory. (The STABLE operations yield a Hopf algebroid instead.) Here is a nice survey by Steve Wilson: https://math.jhu.edu/~wsw/papers2/math/39-hopf-rings-expo-2000.pdf

Comment: P.S. There's a very general machinery for gadgets along such lines, "rings in the category of rings" and "rings in the category of Hopf algebras" and so on: "Tall-Wraith monoids" seem to be designed for such purposes. I think Hopf rings are supposed to be a special case. I cannot say I have ever taken the time to get properly acquainted with Tall-Wraith monoids, but perhaps others who know the theory can say more than I can. The nLab page is here: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Tall-Wraith+monoid